# How can i make a website pull up similar questions as the user is typing?

Tags: php, javascript, html, autocomplete

I was wondering if there was some sort of open source or something that could help me do this.

As the user is typing questions, i want to pull up questions that relate in order so they can get relevant answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you're looking for some kind of auto-complete functionality, like what google does?

Comment: if you "do not have much time" perhaps you should have started this task earlier?

Comment: i got drafted onto a team. this is not my primary responsibility.

Comment: the point is that you are no more special than anyone else.  People on SO will happily help -- but your trying to impart a sense of preferential urgency can be taken amiss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are familiar with jQuery,

[jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Example)

would be your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

Couple jQuery UI's [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) on the frontend with a JSON service on the backend with whatever server side code you're using. 
the jQuery UI docs are really good and you should get started with the Autocomplete tool easily. Without any other knowledge of situation i can't help you further.